# Free space path loss and ofdm

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

I want to apply the Friis equation of free space path loss on OFDM signal. Do I multiply signal by $\frac{c}{4\pi f_cd}$ before IFFT or after?

Comment: Hi Ahmed! I think you can actually answer this yourself with a little thought: Does Free Space Path Loss care about whether your signal is OFDM or something else? The answer to that question already answers your question.

Comment: I want to apply free space path loss with and do channel estimation but when i multiply my subcarriers that are qpsk symbols with the friis equation the MSE decreases

Comment: It's a bit strange that you say "channel estimation" and "Free Space Path Loss" in the same sentence. You are aware that the very fact why you need that channel estimate is that you don't use OFDM systems in flat fading channels: You don't use OFDM where Free Space Path Loss describes the propagation.

Comment: Again, ask yourself: **Does Free Space Path Loss care whether your signal is OFDM or something else?** It's a simple yes/no question, and I think you will find an answer.

Comment: Also ask yourself: at which stage of the communications system does the loss occur?